# ¿Cuál es el significado de la expresión "Juana la Beltraneja"?

Tags: modismos, significado, españa

En la siguiente [noticia](http://www.msn.com/es-co/entretenimiento/noticias/28-pel%C3%ADculas-que-destruyeron-la-carrera-de-sus-protagonistas/ss-BBmtLMw?OCID=mailsignoutes#image=15) se encuentra la siguiente línea:

> "...su estudiada simpatía la convirtió en la **Juana la Beltraneja** de Hollywood.".

Al parecer, **[Juana la Beltraneja](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juana_la_Beltraneja)** fue un personaje histórico; sin embargo, desconozco el origen, uso y significado de este nombre como calificativo.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no es específica del idioma Español. Se pregunta por un asunto de cultura general que puede formar parte de textos en cualquier idioma.

Comment: @Mauricio, no creo que se use en otros idiomas porque está muy ligada a la cultura de un país. En español no se usa por ejemplo la expresión "The British are coming" con el sentido que se puede dar en USA (es de un poema de Paul Revere en el contexto de la guerra de la independencia). No creo que usen la expresión en Gran Bretaña. Pienso que es una referencia, y no un calificativo. Aun así no creo que la pregunta deba cerrarse. Para origen y uso te estás ya respondiendo tú mismo con las referencias. Acerca de su uso como calificativo, posibles respuestas indicarán que sí o no lo es y porqué.

Answer (score 3):

Jamás había oído "Juana la Beltrananeja" o siquiera "la Beltraneja" usado así como calificativo (que no fuera para el personaje histórico). Si dices de alguien que "es un Einstein" probablemente todos entendemos que es un tipo muy listo. Juana la Belatraneja es un personaje un poco más oscuro y hay que conocer al personaje para saber lo que quiere decir.

Citando de la noticia a la que haces referencia, se explica que hay una especie de "ola de odio" hacia la actriz por "*Su estudiada cara de sorpresa cada vez que ganaba un premio, su estudiada simpatía*" que "*la convirtió en la Juana la Beltraneja de Hollywood*".

Leyendo la referencia a LA Beltraneja en el articulo de wikipedia, podemos ver cómo esta mujer fue despojada de todos sus títulos. En especial el apartado de "posteridad" nos dice que

> sus descendientes intentaron borrar de la memoria histórica la existencia de Juana y la sombra de ilegitimidad que arrojaba sobre la reina Isabel

Es decir, que era un personaje no muy querido. Insisto, no creo que sea una expresión común, sino más bien una comparación con un personaje histórico algo rebuscada.

A Anne Hathaway, según la noticia, le ha pasado como a la Beltraneja. Parece que muchos se han cansado de ella y tratan de apartarla o ignorarla.

Comment: me gustaría "si es posible" que considera la redacción de su respuesta. _Leo su respuesta como una opinión personal (sin referencias)_. al usar expresiones como `jamás había oído..` o `insisto, no creo que sea...`. Leí su respuesta varias veces y **no** merece un voto negativo, pero para efectos de que esta pregunta pueda ser útil/de interés para otros usuarios, considero mejor cambiar un poco la redacción _solamente si es posible_. :)
Gracias.

Comment: Es "opinión personal" porque no puedo aportar referencias o un contraejemplo para "demostrar" que "Juana la Beltraneja" no se usa como _calificativo_ (o dicho popular o similar), sino que se ha usado como un _comparativo_ o _referencia histórica_. Se pueden aportar referencias objetivas para demostrar el origen de la expresión o etimología de  XYZ, pero no puedo demostrar que algo es no una expresión sino un "uso aislado" en base a una explicación, conocimiento general del lenguaje (como nativo) y posible falta de usos similares, lo que convierte mi respuesta, por supuesto, en **subjetiva**.

Comment: Habrá quien piense que merece voto negativo y quien piense que merece voto positivo. Al fin y al cabo la validación de otros usuarios de nuestras repuestas es lo que confirma la validez o corrección del contenido de cada respuesta.